# How to add other data in the remaining cell before duplicates are removed VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I have the below table that I need to format and remove duplicates but can't work out how to update column G to add all the fixture belonging to that duplicate on one line that remains after the duplicates are removed and in parenthesis I need the qty scanned per fixture ex 10000(1), 10001(5), 10002(1),10003(10).

```
Sub RemoveDuplicates()
    Dim checkLastRow As Long, r1 As Long
    Dim DeleteRange As Range

   On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
       Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    CopySheet
    With Worksheets("Edited")
        checkLastRow = .Range("D" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For r1 = 6 To checkLastRow
            If .Cells(r1, 4).Value = Cells(r1 + 1, 4).Value Then
                If DeleteRange Is Nothing Then
                    Set DeleteRange = .Rows(r1)
                Else
                    Set DeleteRange = Union(DeleteRange, .Rows(r1))
                End If
            End If
        Next r1

        If Not DeleteRange Is Nothing Then DeleteRange.Delete
    End With
    Range("A:K").UnMerge
    Range("H6:K6").Delete shift:=xlUp
    DeleteBlankRows
    Range("A1:K4").Merge True

UpdateScreen:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
     Debug.Print Err.Number; Err.Description
        MsgBox "Sorry, an error occured." & vbCrLf & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error!"
    Resume UpdateScreen

End Sub

Private Sub CopySheet()
    Dim MySheetName As String
    MySheetName = "Edited"
    Sheets(1).Copy After:=Sheets(1)
    ActiveSheet.Name = MySheetName
End Sub

Private Sub DeleteBlankRows()
    Dim r As Long
    Dim DeleteRange As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long

    With Worksheets("Edited")
        lastRow = .Range("D" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For r = 6 To lastRow
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A" & r & ":" & "D" & r)) = 0 Then
            If DeleteRange Is Nothing Then
                Set DeleteRange = Rows(r)
            Else
                Set DeleteRange = Union(DeleteRange, Rows(r))
            End If
        End If
    Next r

    If Not DeleteRange Is Nothing Then DeleteRange.Delete shift:=xlUp
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Shouldn't `G6` be `10000(1),10003(3)` instead of `10000(1),10003(4)`?

Comment: @siddarth Rout Yes i think it was a miss type from my end sorry about that.

Comment: no worries. do you have the sample file ready so that I do not have to create it? If yes, can you upload it to a free file sharing site and share the link here?

Comment: Quick quesiton. Will the data be always sorted on Col F?

Comment: @Siddharth Rout No should be the D column to check for unique values as that will be the only one that will be unique the rest may be similar so we can check for duplicates there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145280/discussion-between-siddharth-rout-and-quicksilver).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way. It took less than a second to test it on your sample file. It looks big because of the comments :)

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim delRange As Range
    Dim lRow As Long, i As Long

    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    With ws
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        '~~> Delete All rows where Cell A and Cell B are empty
        For i = 6 To lRow
            If Len(Trim(.Range("A" & i).Value)) = 0 Or Len(Trim(.Range("B" & i).Value)) = 0 Then
                If delRange Is Nothing Then
                    Set delRange = .Rows(i)
                Else
                    Set delRange = Union(delRange, .Rows(i))
                End If
            End If
        Next i

        If Not delRange Is Nothing Then delRange.Delete

        '~~> Find the new last row
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        '~~> Insert a new column between G and H
        .Columns(8).Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

        '~~> Insert a formula =G6 & "(" & I6 & ")" in H6
        '~~> Inserting the formula in the entire column in one go
        '~~> and converting it to values
        .Range("H6:H" & lRow).Formula = "=G6 & ""("" & I6 & "")"""
        .Range("H6:H" & lRow).Value = .Range("H6:H" & lRow).Value
        '~~> Copy the header from Col G to Col H so that we can delete the
        '~~> Column G as it is not required anymore
        .Range("H5").Value = .Range("G5").Value
        .Columns(7).Delete

        '~~> Using a reverse loop to append values from bottom row to the row above
        '~~> After appending clear the cell G so that we can later delete the row
        For i = lRow To 7 Step -1
            If .Range("F" & i).Value = .Range("F" & i - 1).Value Then
                .Range("G" & i - 1).Value = .Range("G" & i - 1).Value & "," & .Range("G" & i).Value
                .Range("H" & i - 1).Value = .Range("H" & i - 1).Value + .Range("H" & i).Value
                .Range("G" & i).ClearContents
            End If
        Next i

        Set delRange = Nothing

        '~~> Delete rows where Cell G is empty
        For i = 6 To lRow
            If Len(Trim(.Range("G" & i).Value)) = 0 Then
                If delRange Is Nothing Then
                    Set delRange = .Rows(i)
                Else
                    Set delRange = Union(delRange, .Rows(i))
                End If
            End If
        Next i

        If Not delRange Is Nothing Then delRange.Delete

        '~~> Find the new last row
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        '~~> Calculating the variance
        .Range("J6:J" & lRow).Formula = "=H6-I6"
        .Range("J6:J" & lRow).Value = .Range("J6:J" & lRow).Value
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]